# How can I get precisely a certain cubic cm by changing the following factors?

Tags: geometry

By a calculation of the size of the cubic $\text {cm}$ which its sizes are:  $3.8330 \times  3.8330 \times 5.17455$, I got a volume of $76.02 cm^3$. How can I get precisely "$76.04$" $\text {cm}^3$, by changing the first two mentioned factors (i.e. $3.8330 \times  3.8330 \times 5.17455$) equally?

N.b. I tried many ways and I couldn't find it, always I got more or less but not precisely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To avoid getting caught-up in specific numbers ...

---

Suppose you have
$$a\cdot b \cdot c = d$$
but you want $d$ to become $e$. You can make this happen by multiplying both sides by $e/d$:
$$\left(a\cdot b \cdot c \right)\cdot \frac{e}{d} = d\cdot\frac{e}{d} = e$$

Now, you can use the left-hand side's factor of $e/d$ to make adjustments to $a$, $b$, and/or $c$. If you just wanted to adjust one factor, you could write, say,

> $$\left( a\cdot \frac{e}{d}\right)\cdot b\cdot c \;=\; e \tag{1}$$

If you wanted to adjust two factors proportionally (as is specifically requested in the question), you can "split" $e/d$ equally across the factors using a square root:

> $$\frac{e}{d} = \sqrt{\frac{e}{d}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{e}{d}} \qquad\to\qquad\left(a\cdot \sqrt{\frac{e}{d}}\right)\cdot\left(b\cdot \sqrt{\frac{e}{d}}\right)\cdot c \;=\; e \tag{2}$$

Finally, if you later decide you actually want to adjust your *entire box* proportionally, you can use cube roots:

> $$\left(a\cdot\sqrt[3]\frac{e}{d}\right)\cdot\left(b\cdot\sqrt[3]\frac{e}{d}\right)\cdot \left(c\cdot\sqrt[3]\frac{e}{d}\right) \;=\; e \tag{3}$$

Naturally, the same type of thing works with any number of overall factors and desired adjustments, using higher-level roots as needed.

Comment: I used your way and I found everything that I wanted to find (other examples as well!). thank you very much. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4):

You have $3.833 \times 3.833 \times5.174=76.02 .$

You can change it by multiplying both sides by $\displaystyle \frac{76.04}{76.02}$.

We then have $3.833 \times 3.833 \times5.174 \times \displaystyle \frac{76.04}{76.02}=76.02 \times \displaystyle \frac{76.04}{76.02}$.

This comes out to $3.833 \times 3.833 \times5.17564=76.04 $

Comment: +1 Note that you can multiply any one of the three factors by $76.04/75.02$, although there's an aesthetic argument for keeping the first two equal.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer (1+^). Is there a way to add change the first two parameters (3.833*3.833)? I mean even-though it'll be the same size, but if I want to change these dimensions is important.

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent do you want to change both of the first two parameters? or just one of them?

Comment: you can multiply 3.833 by 76.04/76.02 instead

Comment: You can take any two positive numbers $a$ and $b$, let $c = (76.04/76.02)/ab$ and then multiply each of the factors by $a$, $b$ and $c$. So you can make  any two factors anything you like and adjust the third accordingly. If you want to keep the third factor the same and keep  the first two equal, let $a = b =$ the square root of $76.04/76.02$.

Comment: Thank you Ethan. I'll try to find in the way that you mentioned. @SakethMalyala I'd like to change both of them equally.

Comment: Okay. Try multiplying 3.833 x sqrt(76.04/76.02) for both of them

Answer (score 2):

Actually $3.833 \cdot 3.833 \cdot 5.174 = 76.0158$ so the added volume will be $.0242$

One way is to think of it as adding a sheet $3.833 \cdot 3.833$ with a volume of $0.0242\ \text{cm}^3$. How thick does it have to be to equal that volume?

Hence, $\frac{0.0242}{3.833^2} = .00165$

So the dimensions will be $3.833 \cdot 3.833 \cdot (5.174 + .00165)$

$3.833 \cdot 3.833 \cdot 5.17565 = 76.040$